# GLB (GLTF) export, how to include color/material information?

Tags: export, gltf

As a complete beginner with Blender, I have been creating simple 3D models to export as GLB and import into another program. For this purpose there is no animation, no physics, etc. I just need them to be visually correct.

When I export the object, it is always the default white color. I only need relatively flat color (that is, I don't care about textures nor do I want to map a bitmapped material onto the objects for this particular project), but I do want there to be something besides white.

I would appreciate if any answers were very step-by-step from scratch. Most answers I have seen here assume one is already very familiar with the Blender interface, and I am not. For example, one says to "Set the Workbench viewport to Flat-Vertex color." OK, but there's nothing on the screen with the label Workbench. Is that a Workspace? It seems not. The manual is unhelpful. So more specific instructions like, say, "On the right side of the Blender workspace is an icon like a wrench. Actually there are two wrenches sometimes, I mean the light blue one right next to the workspace. Click that and select foo."

I'm using Blender 2.90. Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's assume you have your model like this. Click on your model to select it. Then open the Material Properties panel by clicking the sphere in the Properties Editor.

[image: Open Material Properties]

Click on the New button to add a new material.

[image: Add new material]

You should see something like this. You can edit the properties of the new material. Click on the Base Color button and a color picker will come up. You can now pick a color.

[image: Change base color]

[image: Color picker]

Your model will now export with the color you picked, but to see the way the model looks with materials applied, make sure the 3D View is in Material Preview mode.

[image: Preview materials]

Also when you export, make sure the Geometry > Materials option is on (it is by default).

Comment: Thank you. That's the exact information I needed. I thought I had done that (except the "Material Preview mode," which I had no idea what the "hourglass superimposed on a circle" icon meant). I must have missed a step. Mind you, Material Preview mode has absolutely no effect, but I'm sure I did something else wrong or missed another step somewhere, and I can export the GLB and import it into my VR environment, and it works, which is my actual need. Thanks again.

Comment: Sorry about the repetitive comments, but ... Material Preview didn't change the preview at all, until I unselected an object and selected a different one, at which point the entire thing (both objects) suddenly updated. No idea what's up with that.