# How do gltf properties (such as material and geometry) map on to what is exported by blender?

Tags: gltf

When I export a blender object as a GLTF file (and then import into a web app), I'm not completely sure as to how the object properties are mapped..

For example, I would usually export an object, and everything needed would be under the material and geometry properties (within the gltf object).

The other day, I combined a few objects into one ([as per here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2632/how-do-i-make-multiple-blender-objects-into-one)), however, noticed that there were no 'material' and 'geometry' properties on the exported object.

I'm still pretty new to blender, so maybe this is quite an obvious question, but any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: As a side note, 'materials' IS selected as per here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/200840/glb-gltf-export-how-to-include-color-material-information

Comment: You can see what the exporter expects materials to look like in [the manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/addons/import_export/scene_gltf2.html). A more concrete question would be easier to answer.

Comment: ah so apparently it is 3 textures that I need to merge (the newly combined object has 3 textures/shaders attached after the merge). I tried this: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/32677/how-to-combine-two-different-textures-into-one but it isn't really the right thing